# Bake normal map for different shape keys?

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine, normals, normal-map

So I've followed the instructions in this video link exactly with my blender character:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ApzVWuPa4A4

The problem is, my normal map isn't showing up on the low poly model. Is it possible that it's not visible because I've already implemented shape keys on the low poly model?﻿

Here's how the low poly model currently looks:
[image: low poly]

This is the high poly model (notice the added brow wrinkles and smile lines):
[image]

I copied my high poly model from the low poly with all of its shapekeys, and sculpted each individual shape key of the high poly model.

Any ideas where I could be going wrong?

Comment: Sorry if the answer is obvious. I just started using blender this week.